# Apple ID not supported - Use a Managed Apple ID Error

Tags: apple-id, mobile-device-management, apple-business

When enrolling in MDM you may get this error if you had previously used the same email address as a non managed id.

e.g. example.com was transferred to Apple Business managed ids, now your old my@example.com Apple ID needs to be removed so you can use the managed version.

Answer (score 1):

To work around this issue:

- open https://appleid.apple.com, login with your old Apple ID and change the email to a new address (eg. my@example2.com)
- on the Mac/iPhone with the issue, add this new Apple Id as a secondary iCloud account
- enroll with your Managed Apple ID
- remove the my@example2.com Apple ID from the device (which can now be deleted)